# Wait for a delay before capture website image with PyQt

Tags: python, macos, flash, qt, pyqt

I'm working with PyQt (as a Python beginner).
I need to be able to take screenshots of a website on a headless system.
I was using PhantomJS earlier for another project, but they dropped Flash support in 1.5 and I don't want to rely on a deprecated 1.4 version for my new project.

So I'm using PyQt to do my stuff on my own.
I'm able to take a screenshot of a website with a given url, no problem.

But I keep having the "blue dice" flash plugin icon on flash placeholder (yes, javascript and plugins are activated)

```
self.settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled,True) 
self.settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled,True)
```

I'm making some test on a Youtube video page, here is an example of my issues:

[image]

The second part, that may be related to the first one: 
How can I tell PyQt to wait few seconds before taking the screenshot ?
As you can see on the example, images on the right are still unloaded, because they are loaded using javascript and data attribute and in my script, I take the screenshot on the **loadFinished** signal (onLoad() javascript equivalent)).

My first guess was simply to

```
time.sleep(2)
```

Before calling my capture method, but it's not working. I'm assuming that the Webkit loading is also asleep during this sleep time, preventing anything to load on the page.

I tried to create a custom signal, but then I still don't know how to trigger it without sleeping.

My last guess is that I need to thread my application. Am I right?

If you have any hint/script to help me displaying flash content and/or to add a setTimeout like signal, I would be really grateful!

Thanks in advance for you help.

**EDIT:**
Just a quick edit to add my solution:

```
timeoutTimer = QTimer()
timeoutTimer.setInterval(3000) # wait for 3secs
timeoutTimer.setSingleShot(True)
timeoutTimer.timeout.connect(theMethodToCallOnTimeout)
```

About the flash thing: it looks like the flash player is broken on OSX (maybe related to a 32/64 bits issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `time.sleep` you are freezing the whole application,  instead, you can use a `QTimer`, `QEventLoop`, `QThread`, etc. Here is the PyQt4 version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(browser, self).__init__(parent)

        self.timerScreen = QTimer()
        self.timerScreen.setInterval(2000)
        self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.takeScreenshot)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)
        self.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com/ncr"))    

    def takeScreenshot(self):    
        image   = QImage(self.page().mainFrame().contentsSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        painter = QPainter(image)

        self.page().mainFrame().render(painter)

        painter.end()
        image.save(self.title() + ".png")

        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys        
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = browser()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: QWebView Screenshot]

Comment: I love Selenium, but this actually answers the question being asked

Comment: Thanks mate. This does not fix my weird issue on Youtube, but this is what I was looking for in the first place. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It is made for doing web automation, screenshots, and testing. Because it uses firefox it is very easy to have full flash support. It can also be run in a headless mode. The code below works at taking a screenshot of a web page with flash like the youtube video you had. You can see the screenshot it took below. A few things to keep in mind. selenium has a save_screenshot method which you can see is commented out in the code. I didn't use it because it wasn't taking proper screenshot of flash components, you can correct this by using the technique in [Taking screenshot of flash object using Selenium with Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642519/taking-screenshot-of-flash-object-using-selenium-with-webdriver). I chose though to just take a screenshot of the screen using the imagemagic import command. This is a screenshot tool that works in Linux. You can check out [Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux) and [Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python) for other approaches of taking screenshots.

**code**

```
import time, selenium.webdriver, subprocess
browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFEoMO0pc7k')
time.sleep(6)
#browser.save_screenshot('test.png')
subprocess.check_output('import -window root screen.png', shell=True)
browser.quit()
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: That's a screenshot of the website + the browser ;)

Comment: @X.Jacobs thats correct, the screenshot is actually the whole screen. I cropped the image for the posting.

Comment: I'll do some tests using Selenium. But I have to say that it's always a bit bothering me when you ask "how to do X on Y" and that somebody answer, well, on Z it's quite easy. Sometime you have to stick to your initial choice and deal with it.
But this can definitely help me, so thank you!

Comment: @MaximeZielony I know what you mean. I tried to do it with PyQt4 first but I couldn't get flash working, so I fell back on to selenium.

Comment: @Marwan Alsabbagh flash video working in Pyside / PyQt4 by enabling plugins.. please check my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377440/pyside-to-take-flash-webvideo-screenshot . i am facing an issue on taking screenshot of this youtube video. it shows black screen